# Кубический сплайн Эрмита

Tags: математика, численные-методы

Не могу понять выражение 3.23.Точнее откуда он вытекает? Как его вывели? По какому соображению это  сделано? и как вообще обосновать его?
Видно,что тут используется дифференцирование и ряд Pf мне чем-то знаком.Но не могу точно догадаться.
Помогите пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Значения и производные которого совпадают со значениями...

Просто составляем систему из четырех уравнений - два значения функции и два значения производных для *x*<sub>*i*</sub>, *x*<sub>*i*+1</sub> - и получаем коэффициенты.

Например, подставляя *x* = *x*<sub>*i*</sub>, сразу получаем первый коэффициент. Беря производную в точке *x* = *x*<sub>*i*</sub> (где исчезает член-константа и обнуляются члены при *с*<sub>2</sub> и *c*<sub>3</sub>, тут же получаем *c*<sub>1</sub>.

Остальные два получаются несколько сложнее, но точно так же - подставляя *x* = *x*<sub>*i*+1</sub> в уравнение функции и производной с учетом уже известных первых двух *c* и получаем искомое...